# How can I keep all the focused forms?

Tags: c#, .net, focus

I've an application that use two forms: Form1 (main) and Form2 (secondary). I show the Form2 with the following code:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.TopMost = true;
frm.Show();
```

When the Form2 is visible, it hasn't the focus. How can I do the focus at the Form2 and keep the focus at the Form1? Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: What do you mean by "keep active forms together"?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried already. Please edit your question to elaborate.

Comment: i think he means by selecting the main window, other application windows won't go to background, just like Paint.NET that has extra windows around it

Answer (score 0):

try bellow code  within MDI Parent Form (Main Form)

```
private Form2 _form2;

#region UtilOpenForm
    /// <summary>
    /// UtilOpenForm
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appContainer"></param>
    /// <param name="childForm"></param>
    private void UtilOpenForm(Form appContainer, Form childForm)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        if (childForm == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("childForm");
        }
        childForm.MdiParent = appContainer;
        childForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        childForm.MaximizeBox = false;
        childForm.MinimizeBox = false;
        childForm.Closed += new EventHandler(childForm_Closed);
        childForm.Show();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Now from Button / Menu click  within MDI Parent

```
    if (_form2 == null)
        {
            UtilOpenForm(this, _form2 = new Form2());
        }
```

Now child form close Function within MDI Parent

```
   #region childForm_Closed
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void childForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.GetType() == typeof(Form2))
        {
            _form2.Dispose();

            if (_form2 != null)
            {
                _form2 = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: OK! If I also have the Form3, how can I do to have (simultaneously) the focus on Form1 (MDI parent), Form2 (child) and Form3 (child)? Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: I want to handle the form such as the last version of Paint.NET

Comment: @developer123: Except main form. All other Form 1,2, 3...N all are child form. Those all take Main form / Form1 as (MDI parent). And all the child form open under MDI Parent.

Comment: OK! I understand. If the children are two, the last child has the focus, while the first hasn't. How can I do to have the focus on both?

Comment: @developer123 : You can do one thing . Say if you have two form : 1 & 2 and both are child form. So When you open a new form after click on Menu --> link : It is automatically focus on Active Form (by default). If 1 form already open. Then Last form get the focus. So the solution is. write a code when you move Mouse on any form it will get the focus. Windows Form have multiple event. Choose your suitable event, to get back the focus on a particular form.

Comment: If I don't use a MDI container, how I can do it on two forms, that they have the property IsMidContainer = false?

Comment: What's an ORM got to do with this? Are you using your answers to advertise?

Comment: @Twon-ha What's an ORM? I'm using the answer for understand the c#

Comment: @developer123 I meant the last line of this answer (The Knight Data Access Layer thing). An ORM is an Object Relation Mapper, and has no real relevance to this question.